# Reference to column title in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm looking for a hint on a particular request.

First of all I am working on PL/SQL on Oracle11gDB and I am doing some function and procedures.

One of theese functions has a SELECT statement. I want to use this function many times, retrieving different values from the same table. Basically I need to change the column in the SELECT statement according to the data I want.

As it is a function, I was wondering if there is a way to pass a variable to this function in order to use it in the SELECT.

In my mind it is something like a "column_header_type" variable... But I doubt it exists.

Anyway, this is an example of my function:

```
      FUNCTION XXX
  (
  a IN VARCHAR2,
  b IN VARCHAR2,
  field IN VARCHAR2
  )RETURN VARCHAR2 is
  l_var VARCHAR2(200);
  BEGIN
    SELECT field 
    INTO l_var
    FROM TABLE01
    WHERE COD_A = a
    AND COD_B = b;
    RETURN l_var;
  END XXX;
```

The parameter "field" cannot be a VARCHAR2, it does not retrieve values, but only the string itself.

I know that there are some other way to get my result, but I wanted to try something more "elegant" than my usual brutal-stone-age-code.

Thanks for your help. 
Marcello

Comment: You'll have to use dynamic SQL to do that, unless you have a small-ish number of possible column names you expect to be passed in. Will the values from any column always be able to fit into l_var; are will they require implicit conversion, or are they always string already?

Comment: I have something like 10 columns on that table that can be used in this function, but this is only a specific case, maybe in other cases I will have dozens...
Luckily all the columns are of the same type.
Thank you for the suggestion, I will look at it

Comment: More perfomant way could be to retrieve the hole raw and have client-side functions to access the columns.

Comment: Well Serg, you are right, but I started all this to avoid client side applications. I am doing a package about statistical analysis and I am afraid it will be heavy for my clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use dynamic SQL:

```
FUNCTION XXX
(
  a IN VARCHAR2,
  b IN VARCHAR2,
  field IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 is
  l_var VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || field ||
    ' FROM TABLE01' ||
    ' WHERE COD_A = :a' ||
    ' AND COD_B = :b'
  INTO l_var USING a, b;
  RETURN l_var;
END XXX;
```

... which means the query won't be parsed until run time, when the column name is known; the overhead of that is slightly mitigated by using bind variables for the filter column values. You should really sanitise the `field` value too and handle anything unexpected that is passed in.

Or have different versions of the query and decide which to use based on the passed string:

```
FUNCTION XXX
(
  a IN VARCHAR2,
  b IN VARCHAR2,
  field IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 is
  l_var VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  CASE field
    WHEN 'column1' THEN
      SELECT column1
      INTO l_var
      FROM TABLE01
      WHERE COD_A = a
      AND COD_B = b;
    WHEN 'column2' THEN
      SELECT column2
      INTO l_var
      FROM TABLE01
      WHERE COD_A = a
      AND COD_B = b;
    ...
  END CASE;

  RETURN l_var;
END XXX;
```

... which allows the code to be parsed and verified at compile time, but introduces duplication and can be harder to maintain, particularly with a lot of potential values for `field`. And you need to pay attention to the case of the value passed in when checking it.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex, really helpful!